# include JST template inside JST

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating, jst

I am using underscopre ( grunt-contrib-jst) JST template to render VIEW.

However, I am in a situation where I need to make reusable html as a partials from template.

can I make a separate .tmpl & include it in parent .tmpl  ?

my code looks like

```
var tmpl = my.namespace['template/hello.tmpl'];
$("#content").html(tmpl({  
   data:data
}));

//where as I need to spearate templates inside hello.tmpl
```